# Reset password implementation in Struts

Tags: java, struts

How to append a class variable having some dynamic value (action class) to a `href` tag so as to send a password reset link using java mail API.

My send method is :

```java
public String sendEmail() {

    try {
       // System.out.println(getEmail_id());
        String link="\"http://localhost:15403/Struts_ApplicationTest/change_Pwd.jsp?=\"";
        body="\n<a href="+link+getEmail_id()+">Click here to reset password</a>";
       // body= "\n<a href='http://localhost:15403/Struts_ApplicationTest/change_Pwd.jsp>Click here to reset password</a>";
        SecurityManager s = new SecurityManager();
        System.out.println("assdddssdsd" + s);
        Session session = Session.getInstance(properties,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {

                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(em_from, em_password);
                    }
                });
        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(em_from));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                InternetAddress.parse(email_id));
        message.setSubject(subject);

        message.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(
                new ByteArrayDataSource(body, "text/html")));

        Transport.send(message);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

        return "error";
    }


    return "sent";

}
```

Using this I am not able to get my passed variable name in my link sent through email.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a string, you append it like any other string value.

Comment: If you two want to discuss the tagging of this question, please take that to Meta: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265943/i-need-clarification-on-tagging-questions-with-technologies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to set some attribute `href` of the anchor tag it should be quoted by single or double quotes. The double quotes needs escaping via Java, rather than single quotes you don't.

```
String link="http://localhost:15403/Struts_ApplicationTest/change_Pwd.jsp?=";
body="\n<a href='"+link+getEmail_id()+"'>Click here to reset password</a>";
```